# Create a VSI within specific vlan and subnet using slcli

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Hi guys I'm trying to create a VSI using slcli and I have to restore an IMAGE and put this VSI within a specific private vlan. Does anyone know the correct parameter I have to use in the slcli command? Here is an example of my command: slcli order place --verify --billing hourly SUSPEND_CLOUD_SERVER SAOPAULO --preset B1_2x8x100 BANDWIDTH_0_GB_2  1_GBPS_PRIVATE_NETWORK_UPLINK 1_IP_ADDRESS MONITORING_HOST_PING NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_AND_TICKET AUTOMATED_NOTIFICATION     UNLIMITED_SSL_VPN_USERS_1_PPTP_VPN_USER_PER_ACCOUNT NESSUS_VULNERABILITY_ASSESSMENT_REPORTING REBOOT_REMOTE_CONSOLE --extras '{"virtualGuests": [{"hostname": "TESTE123", "domain": "xpto.com"}], "imageTemplateId": 1234567 }' --complex-type SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the property [primaryBackendNetworkComponent](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/#primaryBackendNetworkComponent) to specify the private vlan, and **primaryNetworkComponent** if you want to specify the public vlan

Try with the following:

`slcli order place --verify --billing hourly SUSPEND_CLOUD_SERVER SAOPAULO --preset B1_2x8x100 BANDWIDTH_0_GB_2 1_GBPS_PRIVATE_NETWORK_UPLINK 1_IP_ADDRESS MONITORING_HOST_PING NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_AND_TICKET AUTOMATED_NOTIFICATION UNLIMITED_SSL_VPN_USERS_1_PPTP_VPN_USER_PER_ACCOUNT NESSUS_VULNERABILITY_ASSESSMENT_REPORTING REBOOT_REMOTE_CONSOLE --extras '{"virtualGuests": [{"hostname": "TESTE123", "domain": "xpto.com","primaryBackendNetworkComponent":{"networkVlan":{"id":1133322}}}], "imageTemplateId": 1234567 }' --complex-type SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest`

Some useful links:

[SoftLayer API: Order Virtual Server with specific VLAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36550591/softlayer-api-order-virtual-server-with-specific-vlan)

[Create a SoftLayer virtual guest on a specific subnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592080/create-a-softlayer-virtual-guest-on-a-specific-subnet)

Comment: Great!!! Worked for me gracefully! Thanks for the help...  I'm  just not able to specify the subnet in this line. I tried to read the link mentioned above, but it is returning an error... maybe I'm writing the parameter incorrectly. I'm trying to write  the command: ... "primaryBackendNetworkComponent":{"networkVlan:{"id":1234567,"primarySubnet":{"id":7654321}}

Comment: What error message did you get?. Take in count you must to set the ID of a primary subnet and not other kind of subnet

Comment: It's not returning error... it finishes the command successfully but ignores the parameter "primarySubnet":{"id":7654321} and creates in other subnet inside the Vlan {"networkVlan:{"id":1234567 ... what am I missing? :/